# pysftp- How to get the sftp server upload timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pysftp

I've been trying to get the time a file gets uploaded to my SFTP server, sometimes these files are big and get overwritten every day, I've tried ctime, atime and mtime but it still shows up the file modified time and not the time it finished uploading.

For example, the use case is to get the time it actually was available in the server. When using pysftp to get ctime, mtime, atime, it shows 4:30 AM which is the last modified time and not 5:15 AM the time it was uploaded.

without having to monitor the server every 5 minutes or so, is there a way we can get this attribute (last upload time)?

I've been using this code, however mtime (4:30AM) shows the file last modified date and not the server upload date. any thoughts?

```
import pysftp
import os

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

host = 'somehost'
port = 22
user = 'someuser'
password ='samplepass'

with pysftp.Connection(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        username=user,
        password=password,
        cnopts=cnopts
) as sftp:
    sftp_client = sftp
    path = 'root_folder'
    file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr(remotepath=path)
    file_stat = sftp.stat(os.path.join(path, 'file.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**st_mtime** is what outputs the time in seconds

```
from datetime import datetime #For converting from seconds to M/D/Y

attrs=sftp.listdir_attr() #Attributes of all files/directories in the folder
sftpfile=attrs[0] #Just one file for example purposes...

#Convert the time from seconds to MM/DD/YYYY
datetime.fromtimestamp(sftpfile.st_mtime).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Explanations are highly recommended. However it is preferred to put explanations as text, surrounding your code, rather than in comments, except where it strictly should be posted with code as a rule. Consider editing to match the convention for SO posts. Welcome, & thanks for contributing.

Comment: Thanks Jose, unfortunately I don't have a way to reproduce this but as you can see in my attempt, I tried `mtime`, isn't this similar to `st_time` ?